# AppIcon not show on IOS with xamarin / Visual Studio Mac, but work with xcode

Tags: ios, macos, xamarin, visual-studio-mac, appicon

I have wasted now 3 days triying to put the icon on the app.

I use https://makeappicon.com/ and download the files. Replace the AppIcon.appiconset folder. It not work.

I try everything I found, including cleaning, erasing emulator, erasing vs caches, and finally a full clean reinstalling of everything with the Visual Studio Mac installer.

Still the same.

I create a new black project and add the icons.

Still the same.

Finally I create a xcode project, do the same and it work at first try.

Also, I remove the AppIcon in the asset, manually create it again and manually set the icons.

I have in the .fsproj:

```
<ItemGroup>
<Folder Include="Data\" />
<Folder Include="App\img\" />
<Folder Include="App\img\provemax\" />
<Folder Include="Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\" />
</ItemGroup>

<ImageAsset Include="Assets.xcassets\Contents.json" />
<ImageAsset Include="Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Contents.json" />
<ImageAsset Include="Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-20x20%401x.png" />
<ImageAsset Include="Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\ItunesArtwork%402x.png" />
```

P.D: I also create a empty project in C#, same result, link here:

[Link to demo project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r6gkos0tlvnzhzq/basura.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Can you provide some screenshots of the Assets?

Comment: Check whether item group AppIconAndLaunchImages is present in the csproj file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ask in the VS community and was given a solution by Phil Mitchell :

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/398309/icon-not-show-on-ios.html

> Did you check the build warnings when you compiled the app. You should
>   see a bunch of warnings about missing .png files in the AppIcon image
>   set.
>
> Unlike Xcode, VS requires a reference to each iOS asset .png file in
>   the .csproj file as well as the Assets.xcassets Contents.json file.
>   It's redundant; but it's just how VS works.
>
> If you drag each .png file from Finder to the AppIcon viewer in VS it
>   will add the .csproj reference, the warnings should go away and the
>   icons should appear on the devices.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the enclosing  around your assets:

```
<ItemGroup>
<Folder Include="Data\" />
<Folder Include="App\img\" />
<Folder Include="App\img\provemax\" />
<Folder Include="Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<ImageAsset Include="Assets.xcassets\Contents.json" />
<ImageAsset Include="Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Contents.json" />
<ImageAsset Include="Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-20x20%401x.png" />
<ImageAsset Include="Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\ItunesArtwork%402x.png" />
</ItemGroup>
```